# Adding precision while dividing 2 floats in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a piece of code in C# which divides 2 floats and returns the results upto 6 decimal places.
Here is the code that i have written. Problem is I get the results as 0.6 instead of 0.60000. Please advice a possible a solution to this.

Here is the code :

```
float probability=((float)counter/(float)(max+N));
probability = probability * (float)1.000000;                
Console.WriteLine("Probability:{0:N6}",probability.ToString());
```

Comment: Did you know [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c151dt3s.aspx)? See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx) for answer.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I think that's irrelevant. The OP wants to format numbers in a certain way but fails.

Comment: You can write `(float)1.000000` as `1.0f`.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use `ToString` to specify the values to use for the string format.

After calling `ToString`, the second argument to `WriteLine` becomes the string `"0.6"`. The format here is ignored because the runtime is only just evaluating the expression `probability.ToString()`. To fix this, remove `.ToString` because you want the second argument to be treated as a `float`:

```
Console.WriteLine("Probability:{0:N6}",probability);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `Console.WriteLine("Probability: {0:0.000000}", probability)`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings for details.